# element being removes from all arrays in aurelia class

Tags: javascript, arrays, aurelia

I'm writing a simple filter "search" functionality for members. I've got 2 array properties one is `members` which is a list of all the members the other is `filteredMembers` which will be the filtered list of members:

```
getMembers() {
    return this.userService.getMembers(this.authUser.selectedCompany).then(data => {
        if (data.statusCode === 200) {
            this.members = data.content.users.sort(function (a, b) {
                if (a.firstName < b.firstName) return -1;
                if (a.firstName > b.firstName) return 1;
                return 0;
            });

            this.filteredMembers = this.members;
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('error getting members:', err.response);
    });
}
```

Since there hasn't been any filtering yet I just set the `filteredMembers` to equal `members`. So far so good.

Now I can an input search with a keyup event that filters the members depending on what I type in the search box:

```
<input type="search" value.bind="searchQuery" keyup.delegate="filterMembers()">
```

and the function:

```
filterMembers() {
    if(!this.searchQuery) {
        this.filteredMembers = this.members;
        return;
    }
    let filteredCount = this.filteredMembers.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < filteredCount; i++) {
        if (this.filteredMembers[i].lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchQuery.toLowerCase()) == -1) {
            this.filteredMembers.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

So you can see in the function I just check if what ever the user types in the search box is not found within a member's last name then I remove the member from the `filteredMembers` array. If the search query is empty the again I make the `filteredMembers` equal to `members`.

Here is the issue I'm running into for some reason may be a bug in `Aurelia` or may be human error but when I remove the element from `filteredMembers` it is also removing it from the `members` array. I've tried all sort of variations like not setting `filteredMembers` to equal `members` in that initial `getMembers()` function.

Answer (score 1):

If `filteredMembers` and `members` are the same array instance, element removal will be reflected in both properties because both properties are references to the same array instance.

Shallow-clone the `members` array before assigning it to `filteredMembers`.

Change this:

```
if(!this.searchQuery) {
    this.filteredMembers = this.members;
    return;
}
```

To this:

```
if(!this.searchQuery) {
    this.filteredMembers = this.members.slice(0);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was not able to figure out what was causing the issue but I updated my `filterMembers` function to work around the problem.

```
filterMembers() {
    let members: User[] = [];
    if(!this.searchQuery) {
        this.filteredMembers = this.members;
        return;
    }
    let membersCount = this.members.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < membersCount; i++) {
        if (this.members[i].lastName.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.searchQuery.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
            members.push(this.members[i]);
        }
    }
    this.filteredMembers = members;
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it. Typing on my phone is too slow :p

Comment: @mgiesa I gotta say though I do like your filter alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Try the opposite approach: rather than removing elements that don't match, create a new empty array and add the elements that do match. Then set filteredMembers to that new array.
Or use the native filter method (which returns a new array with the results) and write filteredMembers = members.filter(...)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter